# Parse String date to specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a String date:

```
dob = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();` return like "12/2/2012"
```

But I want to convert (before passing it) to this format `"2012212"`, I have tried

```
string newDate = dob.ToString("yyyMMdd")
```

But I got the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)has some invalid arguments

any idea ?

Comment: Why call `ToString` on `reader.GetValue(7)`? Why not cast it as `DateTime`?

Comment: because `dob` was declared as string ..

Comment: reader.GetDateTime(7) return you DateTime object?

Comment: it return string like  '"01/03/2012"' but I want it like `"20120301"`

Comment: split the string dob by '/' then you will get array. Then concat the array items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not Exact  way of getting output but it will work.

```
   string dob = "12/2/2012";
   string[] d1 = dob.Split('/');
   string s = d1[2] + d1[1] + d1[0];
```

Comment: Glad to suggest you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) if underlying return type is `DateTime`

Then you just need..

```
reader.GetDateTime(7).ToString("yyyyMdd");
```

In case, if it is stored and received as a string then I would suggest converting to `DateTime` first and then look for specific format.

```
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd/M/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyyMdd");
```

Comment: @SaifManea which line of code? it should return `2012212`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetValue(7), "dd/M/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date in a String with the format "ddMMyyyy" and want to convert it to "yyyyMMdd" you could do like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "ddMMyyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below method to convert string to date.

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);   
dob = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.GetValue(7).ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", culture).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Thank you.

Comment: For date format in this case you define culture   ? Are your serious?